# xsl can not get the value of attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf, skos

This is related to a question i posted here [xslt get element value based on attribute which is referenced in another node tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700890/xslt-get-element-value-based-on-attribute-which-is-referenced-in-another-node-tr/31701576?noredirect=1#comment51396979_31701576) I'm trying out first to get the value of an attribute but I can't seem to get it, here again is the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <root>
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#"
   xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
   xmlns:ns0="http://art.uniroma2.it/ontologies/vocbench#"
   xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">

  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321">
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس ماریزی‌ای</skos:prefLabel>
      ....
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
      ....
   <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </skos:Concept>

  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/skosmos/agrovoc/en/page/c_1591">
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">أشجار عيد الميلاد</skos:prefLabel>
        ....
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">christmas trees</skos:prefLabel>
     ....

  </skos:Concept>

     ....

  <skos:Concept>
   <ns0:isUsedAs rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/skosmos/agrovoc/en/page/c_7776"/>
   <ns0:isUsedAs rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/skosmos/agrovoc/en/page/c_1591"/>
  </skos:Concept>

 </rdf:RDF>    
 </root>
```

I have the following templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  ....
 xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
   <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:narrowMatch" />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:exactMatch" />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept" />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/skos:altLabel" />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/skos:prefLabel" />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/ns0:isUsedAs" />
<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> 
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="//ns0:isUsedAs">
  <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource]" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was just trying to get the value of the attribute of skos:Concept rdf:resource with the main templates I already have, but I can't seem to print the values.
I've also tried using variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="ns0isUsedAsvar" select="skos:Concept/ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource]"/ >
```

And then call that variable:

```
<xsl:template match="//ns0:isUsedAs">
 <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="$ns0isUsedAsvar" />
</xsl:template>
```

But I can't seem to make it work. What could be the problem? TIA!

update (in response to Eric):
Here are my namespaces declaration:
    
And I guess I was able to declare all of them. Following your cue with following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
 <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
  <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/ns0:isUsedAs" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> 
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:isUsedAs">
 <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
</xsl:template>
```

I am instead getting the following:

```
START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
آبیس ماریزی‌ای大白叶冷杉Abies mariesii
```

which probably means it gets all node elements with attribute rdf:resource.

update2: particular file can be found here: http://128.199.159.143/merged-file.xml

Update3:

The transformation I am currently using can be find below, I will be adding the code in this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#"
 xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
 xmlns:ns0="http://art.uniroma2.it/ontologies/vocbench#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:ns1="http://art.uniroma2.it/ontologies/vocbench#"
 xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
 <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
     <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:narrowMatch" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:exactMatch" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/skos:altLabel" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skos:narrowMatch">
 <xsl:text>=300  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skos:exactMatch">
 <xsl:text>=300  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skos:Concept[ns0:hasStatus]">
 <xsl:text>=300  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@rdf:about" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skos:Concept">
 <xsl:for-each select="skos:prefLabel|skos:Concept" />
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="skos:broader">
 <xsl:text>=301  \\$abroader$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
 <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@rdf:about" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="skos:narrower">
 <xsl:text>=302  \\$anarrower$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
 <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@rdf:about" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="skos:definition/skos:Description/rdf-value">
 <xsl:text>=303  \\$aDefinition$b</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@xml:lang" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skos:Concept/skos:altLabel">
 <xsl:text>=304  \\$aAltLabel$b</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." />
 <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@xml:lang" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Update 4:
The xslt that I tried that worked with a small sample based on my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   ....
 xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
 <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
  <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/rdf:Description" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:isUsedAs">
 <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Don't get it. When i run your sample xml with your last xslt (template match='root' + template match='ns0:isUsedAs'), i have as results :
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500&#xD;
=305  \\$aisUsedAs$bhttp://aims.fao.org/skosmos/agrovoc/en/page/c_7776=305  \\$aisUsedAs$bhttp://aims.fao.org/skosmos/agrovoc/en/page/c_1591&#xD;

Comment: Give us the exact transformation you're using, the issue could be somewhere else.

Comment: Can I send you the file instead Eric? It's 2057 lines. maybe there's something with the file that I am not able to see.

Comment: Hi Eric. I updated my question, adding the xslt I presently have.

Comment: Hi again Eric! I can confirm that I am getting what I'm trying to get with the provided XSLT, I put it in update 4 of my question. Probably, there is something in my xml that I don't see better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:isUsedAs">
 <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource][1]">
 <xsl:text>=305  \\$aisUsedAs$b</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
</xsl:template>
```

If you want the template to match the first `ns0:isUsedAs` with an `rdf:resource` attribute and you want that template to only ever handle the first of these elements.

Alternatively, if you want to leave the template as is and just match the first one with your `xsl:apply-templates`, you should change the apply templates line to this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept/ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource][1]" />
```

Comment: Maybe, it would be better to make the change you suggest in the apply-templates instruction rather than in the template match.

Comment: Good call.  I'll provide both options.

Comment: Hi all! Please find the file I've been working on here (also, I updated my question adding the link of the file): http://128.199.159.143/merged-file.xml

Answer (score 0):

An exhaustive xslt would be better to help.

First of all, check that all the namespaces are well declared in both the xml input and the xslt stylesheet.
Then, neither your "main template", nor your "variable call" could work. You have context issues.

For your template : 
First, you should escape the '//' in the match, it's useless and confusing, the context of a match is never absolute, it's always relative to the apply-templates context.
Second, when you're in your template, the context is already a "ns0:isUsedAs", you don't need to put it in the xpath. So try directly :

```
<xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
```

Or eventually

```
<xsl:value-of select="self::ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource]" />
```

Note the self:: axis, without explicit axis, it's the child one which is used, then in your tries, you're implicitely looking for ns0:isUsedAs child of a ns0:isUsedAs.

With your variable, they're several problems. If you want to use a variable for this purpose, be cautious, you'll need to define it in the right context. In the skos:Concept template probably. Then, just use :

```
<xsl:template match="skos:Concept">
...
     <xsl:variable name="ns0isUsedAsvar" select="ns0:isUsedAs[@rdf:resource]"/>
...
</xsl:template>
```